# How to start multiple windows from F# using Elmish.WPF?

Tags: f#, elmish-wpf

I am a newbie to Elmish.WPF and F#. In studying the tutorial on NewWindow/NewWindow.Views, the authors have assigned the following code from C# :

```
using System;
using Elmish.WPF.Samples.NewWindow;
using static Elmish.WPF.Samples.NewWindow.Program;

namespace NewWindow.Views {
  public static class Program {
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main() =>
      main(new MainWindow(), () => new Window1(), () => new Window2());
  }
}
```

That is calling the main method in the F# NewWindow.Views project:

```
let main mainWindow (createWindow1: Func<#Window>) (createWindow2: Func<#Window>) =
  let createWindow1 () = createWindow1.Invoke()
  let createWindow2 () =
    let window = createWindow2.Invoke()
    window.Owner <- mainWindow
    window
  let bindings = App.mainBindings createWindow1 createWindow2
  Program.mkSimpleWpf App.init App.update bindings
  |> Program.withConsoleTrace
  |> Program.runWindowWithConfig
    { ElmConfig.Default with LogConsole = true; Measure = true }
    mainWindow
```

How can the F# module main routine be changed so as to use it directly as the EntryPoint and avoid it being a function? That is, I would like the F# module to have direct control over the windows via Elmish.  Something along the lines as below but with the invocation of the subordinate windows self-contained:

```
/// This is the application's entry point. It hands things off to Elmish.WPF
[<EntryPoint; STAThread>]
let main _ =
  Program.mkSimpleWpf init update bindings
  |> Program.runWindow (MainWindow())
```

In short, I would like the C# Views to have no knowledge of the F# project.

Can this be done with Elmish.wpf?

Any help (especially sample code :) ) would be most helpful.

Comment: I am one of the maintainers of Elmish.WPF. I am curious - could you describe [in the issue Tyson created](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/issues/261) why you want the F# project to be the entry point? It may be important for us to know this, so we can continue to design the library accordingly. :)

Answer (score 3):

I am one of the maintainers of Elmish.WPF.  Until very recently, all the samples used their F# project as the entry point.  If you clone the repo and check out [this commit](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/51ea9f210244c17e0d54773e46cc824cc7457d03), then you can inspect those samples and see how to achieve your goal.

Going forward, I created [this issue](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/issues/261) to consider including at least one sample with an F# project as its entry point.

In the future, feel free to ask any of your Elmish.WPF questions by opening an issue in [our GitHub](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF).

Comment: A friend of mine directed me to this question.  I am subscribed to #elmish-wpf, but I have yet to receive a notification for this question.